# Text into table format with stringi

Tags: r, string, stringi

I am trying to take the text that I extracted from some images to a table format in R.

I've been trying to use the stringi package to be able to separate the text into parts, but I have trouble identifying the right pattern. The text combines blanks with numbers and text, so that the separators are not uniform.

```
 >data$V1[c(15,16,17,19)]
[1] "FECHA SUCURSAL DESCRIPCION N|| DCTO CHEQUES Y OTROS DEPOSITOS Y OTROS SALDO"
[2] "CARGOS ABONOS"  
[3] "02/05 Agustinas Egreso por Compra de Divisas 4.841 143.340"                  
[4] "03/05 Agustinas Traspaso Internet desde LCr®dit0 5.000"
```

I have dealt with expressions like this

```
stri_split(data$V1[18], regex ="\\s++")
```

The result I'm looking for is something like this into a data.frame:

```
|------|---------|--------------|------|---------------|-----------------|-------|
|FECHA |SUCURSAL |DESCRIPCION   |N DCTO|CHEQUES Y OTROS|DEPOSITOS Y OTROS|SALDO|
|------|---------|--------------|------|---------------|-----------------|-------|

|------|---------|--------------|------|CARGOS         |ABONOS-----------|-------|
|------|---------|--------------|------|---------------|-----------------|-------|

|02/05 |Agustinas| Egreso por...|------|4.841----------|-----------------|143.340|
|------|---------|--------------|------|---------------|-----------------|-------|
|03/05 |Agustinas|Traspaso .....|------|---------------|5.000------------|-------|
|------|---------|--------------|------|---------------|-----------------|-------|
```

Comment: There is no way to parse that text IMO. You're better off going back to the original image to try another method of converting the data to a table. I think you're better off converting the image to a PDF and using something like `tabularize` to attempt to extract the data.

Comment: @Amar Could you write this as response? Tabulizer Is exactly what i need. Thanks